# Scala futures and method call backs using spray routing

Tags: scala, callback, future, spray

I have this problem where I want to call a future in spray routing. I have tried below and I have it working and return the future value in onComplete

```
 def sendFuture(input):Future[String]= Future {
   //some string manipulation
   result
 }

post {
    entity(as[String]) { 
      input =>
      {           
        onComplete(sendFuture(input)) {
          case Success(result) => { 

            complete("received: " + result)

         }
          case Failure(ex) => complete("An error occurred: " + ex.getMessage())
        }

      }
   }
}
```

Now, I now want to do something more complex. I want to do a call a callback that accepts an argument inside sendFuture and return that string to sendFuture before sendFuture returns it to onComplete. Something like below:

```
 def sendFuture(input):Future[String]= Future {
   //some string manipulation
   callBack.call(
     (arg:String)=>
     {
        //some string manipulation
        return callBackResult
     }
   )
   //do something with result based on callBackResult
   result
 }

post {
    entity(as[String]) { 
      input =>
      {           
        onComplete(sendFuture(input)) {
          case Success(result) => { 

            complete("received: " + result)

         }
          case Failure(ex) => complete("An error occurred: " + ex.getMessage())
        }

      }
   }
}
```

If only callBack.call() would return a string but I it is a void/unit function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split `sendFuture` into two function and use `map` on the result (which is a future) of the first function, but i don't know where you get this `callback.call` stuff, that's not Scala `Future`. Anyway the logic is simple:

The first part of the function should contain a promise, which would expect the result of your callback (everything belongs to Scala implementation of Futures), e.g:

```
def computeFirstpart(input: String): Future[String] = {
  val promise: Promise[String] = Promise()
  // do something with your string
  callback.onComplete { case v => promise.complete(v) }
  promise.future
}
```

This part returns the result of your callback. Now you can attach more computations:

```
def sendFuture(input: String): Future[String] = {
  computeFirstPart(input) flatMap { resultOfFirstPart =>
    // do what you need
    result // NOTE 1
  }
}
```

**NOTE 1** The result should be in **Future** context, you are returning simple type (like `String`) use `map`, not `flatMap`. Then use it in your route structure:

```
post {
    entity(as[String]) { input =>
        onComplete(sendFuture(input)) {
          case Success(result) =>
            complete("received: " + result)
          case Failure(ex) => 
            complete("An error occurred: " + ex.getMessage())
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand how this part works:

`callback.onComplete { case v => promise.complete(v) }`

The callBack in my original code is a java class and it does not have a method "onComplete". Its only method is call() which accepts a function that accepts a string but returns nothing